# Is it possible to reduce ffmpeg commands in a single file pass?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add the logo and telephone number on video, therefore I run the following command twice with different parameters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i ./assets/logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*1/5':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" 'uploads/output.mp4' 2>&1

ffmpeg -i ./uploads/output.mp4 -i ./assets/telephone.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*9/10':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" './uploads/output2.mp4'
```

I'm looking to optimize speed, maybe is possible to have a single file pass instead of 2?

Thank you very much!

I tried

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i ./assets/logo.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*1/5':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" -i ./assets/telephone.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*9/10':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10" './uploads/output2.mp4'
```

but does not add the telephone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way:

```
 ffmpeg  -i uploads/input.mp4 -i ./assets/logo.png -i ./assets/telefon.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=w='iw*1/5':h='ow/mdar'[v1];[2][0]scale2ref=w='iw*9/10':h='ow/mdar'[v2];[0][v1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5[vid];[vid][v2]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10"  uploads/output.mp4
```